# Can I use virtual tokens (tokens with identical return value) in ANTLR4 similar to c++?

Tags: c++, antlr4

In C++ I can use virtual functions to process data from similar classes that have the same parent/ancestor, does ANTLR4 support this and how would I have to set up the grammar?

I have tried to set up a grammar, using arguments that have the same return value and use that value in a token that contains the different "subclassed" tokens.

Here is some code I have tried to work with:

```
    amf_group 
        : statements=amf_statements (GROUPSEP WS? LINE_COMMENT? EOL? | EOF)
        ;

    amf_statements returns [amf::AmfStatements stmts]
        : ( WS? ( stmt=amf_statement { stmts.emplace_back(std::move($stmt.stmtptr)); } WS? EOL) )*
        ;

    amf_statement returns [amf::AmfStatementPtr stmtptr] 
        : (
            stmt = jsonparent_statement 

            | stmt = jsonvalue_statement

           )
        { 
            $stmtptr = std::move($stmt.stmtptr);
        }
        ;

    jsonparent_statement returns [amf::AmfStatementPtr stmtptr] locals [int lineno=0]
        :
        (T_JSONPAR      { $lineno = $T_JSONPAR.line;} )  WS (arg=integer_const)
        {
            $stmtptr = std::make_shared<amf::JSONParentStatement>($lineno, nullptr);
        }
        ;

    jsonvalue_statement returns [amf::AmfStatementPtr stmtptr] locals [int lineno=0]
        : ( T_JSONVALUE { $lineno = $T_JSONVALUE.line; } ) WS (arg=integer_const) (WS fmt=integer_const)?
        {
            $stmtptr = std::make_shared<amf::JSONValueStatement>($lineno, std::move($arg.argptr), std::move($fmt.argptr));
        }
        ;
```

I receive the following error:

error(75): amf1.g4:23:10: label stmt=jsonvalue_statement type mismatch with previous definition: stmt=jsonparent_statement

This error is or course quite logical, because the tokens are indeed of a different type, but there return value types are identical. For two (virtual) tokens I can write all the code separatelty, but in my case I have some 40+ different tokens that either represent arguments or statements and writing all the combinations would be cumbersome. The above code did work in Antlr3 by the way.

Is there another way to get around these errors using ANTLR4? Does anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

What's specified in a rule return value is not really a return value in a functional sense. Instead the context representing the rule will get a new member field that takes the "return" value. Given that it makes no sense trying to treat parser rules like C++ functions, they are simply not comparable.

Instead of handling all the fields in your grammar, I recommend a different approach: with ANTLR4 you will get a parse tree (if enabled), which represents the matched rules using parse rule contexts (which is super view of the previously generated AST). This context contains all the values that have been parsed out. You just need a listener in a second step after the parse run (often called the semantic phase) to walk over this tree, pick those values up and create your own data structures from them. This separation also allows to use your parser for quick syntax checks, since you don't do all the heavy work in the parse run.

Comment: Mike, thanks for the clarification. The current approach is indeed to let the parser construct the data structures, because of performance issues (the parser is used in a REST API backend where performance can be quite an issue), I will reconsider this, add a listener and do some performance testing to compare both approaches.